# Finding the time in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, time

I need to find the current time for my iphone app. I need it broken up into the different units, so I need the hour, minute, and second in different variables. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];

[calendar release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate           *date           = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar       *calendar       = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit    unitFlags      = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

NSInteger hour   = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];

NSLog(@"%ld:%ld:%ld", hour, minute, second);
```

> > 23:34:6

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
int hour = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
int minute = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
int second = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: This works, but `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` are the way to go.

Comment: You can also format "HHmmss" or some such and then substring.  NSDateComponents is a little clumsy since you have to create a calendar first.